# Null value when send Post data using Ajax Jquery in Django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I am trying to makes pagination in django, i need some value (pagesNumber,SearchWord,Categories) to makes some query work ,but i cant get my post data from ajax jquery.I have succeeded in running jquery

This my code

CDN

```
<script src="{% static 'plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js' %} "></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
    <script src="{% static 'plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js' %} "></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

scripts

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$('#submits li').click(function () {
    var a = this.id;
    
    linkUrl = 'library/postNewRA/71/' + a + ''
    alert(linkUrl);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: linkUrl,
        data: {
            'pages': "testValue",
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
        },
        dataType: jsonp,
        success: function (result) {
            window.console.log('Successful');//I CANT GET THIS MESSAGES TOO
        },
        error: function () {
            window.console.log('Error!');//I CANT GET THIS MESSAGES TOO
        }

    });
});
```

});

views.py

```
def postNewRA2  (request,raID,page):
    pages = request.POST.get('pages',None) # this result "None"
    return JsonResponse({"pages":pages})
```

urls.py

```
 path('postNewRA/<int:raID>/<int:page>',views.postNewRA2,name  = "postNewRA2"),
```

Comment: Should `dataType: jsonp,` actually be `dataType: "jsonp",` ?

Comment: still get null value,do i need content value? @JhonTyner

Answer (score 0):

This typo would cause an issue like that

```
$('#submits li').click(function () {
    var a = this.id;
```

should be

```
$('#submits li').click(function () {
    var a = $(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: still have same null value,i get this warn in console "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json" you know what it means?